# Opening AppImage does nothing. What can I do?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, imagemagick

I am a complete newbie to Linux and trying to open an AppImage called Magick which is an Imagemagick application.

I tried right clicking on the AppImage and checked "run file as an executable" option but that didn't work. Another thing that I tried is running this command,

```
chmod a+x magick.AppImage
```

This gives me an error,

```
chmod: cannot access 'magick.AppImage': No such file or directory
```

I have also tried running the file by navigating into the folder that contains the file and opening up the terminal there but still no luck.

I am running Ubuntu on Oracle VM VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageMagick is a command-line tool, you don't run it by clicking on it.

To run it in a terminal you need to

1. Set the executable flag on the .AppImage (once for all): `chmod +x TheApp.AppImage`
2. Then to run it just invoke the AppImage: `./TheApp.AppImage <arg1> <arg2> ...`.

If the directory with your .AppImage is in your PATH, you can remove the `./` (or whatever directory the AppImage is in).

ImageMagick is also available as a regular application from your Ubuntu repository: `sudo apt install imagemagick`

Comment: Yeah, I got it working by installing through command line. Thanks! Btw any idea how I can get the location of my pointer on the image so that I can use the crop attribute of imagemagick to crop my image?

Comment: Use a screen ruler (`kruler` or equivalent)? But if you need to use a pointer, you can also use a GUI image editor (Gimp or else).